# Type.GetType return null

Tags: c#, gettype

I am trying to use Type.GetType and pass "caLibClient.entity.Web2ImageEntity" full class name.  The caLibClient.entity is namespace, located in separated assembly (caLibClient) and added to program reference assemblies list. The Type.GetType always return Null when I call it from program, what is wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add the assembly name as well, since your type isn't in the *executing* assembly (nor mscorlib.) So the call should be:

```
var myType = Type.GetType("caLibClient.entity.Web2ImageEntity, FullAssemblyName");
```

From the [`Type.GetType()` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

> **typeName**
>       **Type**: `System.String`
>       The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
>   AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace.

From the [docs for `AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx), this is a sample name:

```
TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass+NestedClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089
```

**Update**: If you're already referencing the assembly in your project, and know at compile-time what the type-name is, you're better off saying

```
Type myType = typeof(caLibClient.entity.Web2ImageEntity);
```

since now you don't need to search for the type at run-time; the compiler will do everything for you.

Comment: How to find full assembly name? Not sure if I understand correctly what does it mean. Where to look?

Comment: @Tomas What is the name of the assembly that you referenced?

Answer (score 2):

Try `Type.GetType("caLibClient.entity.Web2ImageEntity, caLibClient")`, according to [Assembly qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an [assembly qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx), in your case something like this:

```
var yourType = Type.GetType("caLibClient.entity.Web2ImageEntity,caLibClient");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know a type in the assembly that the target type lives in you can avoid hard coding the full assembly qualified name. For example:

```
Type.GetType(
    "MyAssembly.Foo.BarSubclass, " + typeof(MyAssembly.Foo.IBar).Assembly.FullName)
```