# How to return column names by passing table name using Entity Framework in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

What i have tried so far,
Passed  "tablename" as a dynamic string in the below coding.

```
public List GetColumnNames(string tablename)
{
    using (var Context = new MCPEntities())
    {
        var names = typeof(AdministratorInformation).GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name).ToArray();
        return names.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the above code? It can be achieved simply by reflection on the table type, like you have done. FYI you don't need the context or EF in the approach you are trying.

Comment: "string tablename" is dropdown list selected value(table name),I just want to display column names of the respected selected table name from drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I haven't tested it though.
Create a method that returns a list of properties of a specific type. If you are using MVC then this can be a controller action.

```
public ActionResult ColumnNames(string tableName)
    {
        var columns = Type.GetType("MyNamespace." + tableName).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        return Json(columns, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Bind the result to a dropdown.

Comment: Getting Null reference exception error here,                                                    var columns = Type.GetType(tableName).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to provide a fully qualified path.

Comment: "MyNamespace." means?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283768/type-gettype-return-null